# Cross Domain JSONP over HTTPS

Tags: jquery, https, cross-domain, jsonp

I am using JSONP over HTTP on different domains (say http://a.com and http://b.com) to exchanges messages.

It works fine. My question is, if I switch both host protocols to HTTPS despite the fact that they are on a different domains. Will they continue to work fine without any warning popup warning in IE6?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will continue to work. Changing the protocol is the same effect as changing any other part of the URL -- it will trigger a violation of the same-origin policy and force you into cross-domain mode. If you already have cross-domain access working, it will continue to work with https as well as it did with http.

Note that you'll still need to deal with the situation where one or both of your secure sites has invalid certificate credentials. If you try to execute an AJAX method against a secure URL with a non-trusted or expired certificate the browser **will** warn your user about that, regardless of how or what you're trying to do.

Comment: In Chrome at least, when I make an AJAX request to an https URL with an invalid certificate, it just puts an error in the console.  The browser never prompts me "are you sure" about the certificate.